# Can't Connect to Terminal Server with Mac OS X Client

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, osx-mountain-lion, terminal-server

I downloaded Microsoft's RDP client for Mac OSX and when I try to connect to the Terminal Server at work it won't allow me to connect.  I get the following error:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2013-03-14 03:01:56 +0000
Application Name: Remote Desktop Connection
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.rdc
Application Signature: MSRD
Application Version: 2.1.1.110309
Crashed Module Name: unknown
Crashed Module Version: unknown
Crashed Module Offset: unknown
Blame Module Name: unknown
Blame Module Version: unknown
Blame Module Offset: unknown
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409 
Crashed thread: 0
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Please don't create new tags unless absolutely necessary – we already had one for 10.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless it has been resolved, there are known issues with RDP between certain versions of OSX and certain version of Windows Server. See:

http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/rdc/item/53c85d88-67e2-4ee3-8667-f9490bc9a257

I'd try another client (e.g., [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/)). If CoRD works, then you know it's not so much a bug/config problem, but the RDP issue referenced above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Ericom Blaze.  Besides connecting to Terminal Server from  Mac OSX, it will also accelerate and compress RDP, so it can improve performance if you need to open files like PDFs or PPTs.

Click here for more info:

[http://www.ericom.com/Blaze4Mac](http://www.ericom.com/mac-linux-windows.asp?URL_ID=708)

Please note that I work for Ericom